# Как отредактировать конкретное поле класса и отдать этот экземпляр класса функции, не редактируя сам экземпляр класса?

Tags: c++

Есть у меня код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    queue<point> q;
    point start{ 0, 0 };
    q.push(start); //но я хочу отдать start = {x - 1, y}, то есть {-1, 0} 
    //при этом оставив значение {0, 0} в самой переменной.
}
```

То есть, что я хочу:

Отдать в аргументы функции `push()` - переменную `start`, но при этом хочу, чтобы поле `start.x` было каким либо образом изменено (в моем примере хочу уменьшить поле `start.x` на 1), но сама переменная `start` не менялась.

Возможно ли реализовать это?

Comment: `q.push(point(start.x-1,start.y))`, например. Или допишите соответствующий функционал в `point`.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Приведите выходные данные и добавьте `std::` для `std::queue`

Comment: В структуру добавьте `enum { k = -1 };
    point(int a = 0, int b = 0) : x(a), y(b){}
    point(const point& p) : x(p.x + k), y(p.y){}` , тогда при копировании получите измененные данные. Можете  значение k задать и в конструкторе. Важно знать зачем это, чтобы решить  лучшим образом

Comment: @dIm0n поправил, посмотрите

Comment: `q.push({start.x-1, start.y});` подойдёт?